# width of input in filter toolbar seems to be too long in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have observed strange issue with jqGrid. The issue is minor and related more to presentation than functionality.

When I toggle filter toolbar, width of input for a column does not fit width of column. Actually, it is more than that of column.

You can see same issue in demos at http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html.

Please check for Searching->Toolbar with Operations. Once you load demo, please check width of filter input for column Index.

Or you can check New in version 3.5->Integrated Search Toolbar. Once you load demo, please check width of filter inputs.

Any solution?

Regards

Comment: Which web browser you use in your tests. I can see wrong width only in Google Chrome 27.0.1453.110 and see no problems in IE10, Firefox 21, Opera 12.15. I see additionally **no searching operation** in "Searching" / "Toolbar with Operations" demo in Opera 12.15.

Comment: I am using chrome 27.0.1453.110 m. 

Btw, I can see searching operations in Searching/Toolbar with Operations in Opera. I am using 12.15.

Comment: Thanks, The problem in Opera are fixed after clearing the local cache. So it's not a problem in jqGrid in general, but just because of usage of wrong caching headers in the demo. I will try examine the problem with width in WebKit (Chrome and Safari) and will post later my suggestion how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that it's a bug in WebKit (Google Chrome 27.0.1453.110 and Safari). I can not only confirm the problem, but describe more hart bug: if you will try to enter "some long text" in the searching toolbar in "Searching"->"Toolbar with Operations" you will have the picture like

[image]

where **no searching operation will be seen**.

jqGrid set inline `style` with `width` value of `<input>` element to `100%` and WebKit caclulate it in a wrong way. As a workaround I suggest to add the following CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>input,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>select { display: block }
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GridWithSearchingToolbar1.htm).

Usage of `box-sizing: border-box;` or

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>input,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>select {
     display: block;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

improves the visibility of the input fields additionally (in my opinion). [The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GridWithSearchingToolbar1_.htm) demonstrates the results. The demo looks identical in my opinion in all web browsers in which I tested the demo.

**UPDATED**: I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-width-of-some-input-fields-of-searching-toolbar-in-webkit-browsers/#p28976) with my suggestion. Now (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/225100f6c09ffbace309c74a794eea27b5238512)) the corresponding changes are already included in the main code of jqGrid on github and the next version (after 4.5.2) of jqGrid will not have more the described problem.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg, for prompt response.

Comment: @isntn: You are welcome! Can you confirm that my suggestions fix the problem in your project? By the way, I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-width-of-some-input-fields-of-searching-toolbar-in-webkit-browsers/#p28976) to trirand.

Comment: Solution you suggested seems to work with text inputs. I also added

    .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>select { display: block }

as I have boolean value column. Can you please help me with datepicker integrated column too?

Comment: @isntn: You are right with `<select>` I modified the demos. [the last demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GridWithSearchingToolbar1_.htm) uses datepicker. Which problem you have?

Comment: @isntn: I included `.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>select` rule in my answer too.

Comment: same width issue...but I can see that in your demo that issue is not there. I think, I need to check my code. 

Thanks, Oleg.

Comment: @isntn: You are welcome! I can imagine that one could need to add more CSS in the same way. It you would have more information about the problem, please inform me.

Comment: @isntn: See **UPDATED** part of my answer: the bug is fixed in the main code of jqGrid.