# jqGrid filter toolbar show search operator selector just for single column

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have jqGrid table with many columns. Searching in grid is made using filter toolbar. For most of them search is just simple default operator. For one datetime column I want different kind of operators and datepicker selector.
I have added `dataInit` datepicker initialization to `searchoptions`, necessary operators to `searchoptions.sopt`. To show this operators I have set searchOperators to true. So for this column all is ok. I have datepicker with operator selector popup. But for all other columns default operator icon is shown on the left of it. It is annoying as operator is default and user couldn't change it. So is there is some possibility to hide them using jqGrid API? As far as I could see I could hide this only using my custom code:

I need to check my column model and after rendering of grid (may be in `loadComplete`) for all columns that have empty `sopt` or `sopt.length == 0` to remove operator selector. Or add CSS class that hide it. Not sure which of these solution is better (hide or remove) because removing could broke some logic, and hiding could affect width calculation. Here is sample of what I mean on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yauhen/Jg2DT/)

```js
function fixSearchOperators()
{
    var columns = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel');
    var gridContainer = $("#grid").parents(".ui-jqgrid");
    var filterToolbar = $("tr.ui-search-toolbar", gridContainer);

    filterToolbar.find("th").each(function()
    {
        var index = $(this).index();
        if(!(columns[index].searchoptions &&
             columns[index].searchoptions.sopt &&
             columns[index].searchoptions.sopt.length>1))
        {
            $(this).find(".ui-search-oper").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Does anybody have some better ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I find the idea to define visibility of searching operations *in every column* very good idea. +1 from me.

I would only suggest you to change a little the criteria for choosing which columns of searching toolbar will get the searching operations. It seems to me more native to include some new property inside of `searchoptions`. So that you can write something like

```js
searchoptions: {
    searchOperators: true,
    sopt: ["gt", "eq"],
    dataInit: function(elem) {
        $(elem).datepicker();
    }
}
```

I think that some columns, like the columns with `stype: "select"`, could still need to have `sopt` (at least `sopt: ["eq"]`), but one don't want to see search operators for such columns. Specifying of visibility of searching operations on the column level would be very practical in such cases.

The modified fiddle demo you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg2DT/9/). I included in the demo CSS from [the fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/225100f6c09ffbace309c74a794eea27b5238512) (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17028298/315935) and [the corresponding bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-width-of-some-input-fields-of-searching-toolbar-in-webkit-browsers/#p28976)). The full code is below

```js
var dataArr = [
    {id:1, name: 'steven', surname: "sanderson", startdate:'06/30/2013'},
    {id:2, name: "valery", surname: "vitko", startdate: '07/27/2013'},
    {id:3, name: "John", surname: "Smith", startdate: '12/30/2012'}];

function fixSearchOperators() {
    var $grid = $("#grid"),
        columns = $grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel'),
        filterToolbar = $($grid[0].grid.hDiv).find("tr.ui-search-toolbar");

    filterToolbar.find("th").each(function(index) {
        var $searchOper = $(this).find(".ui-search-oper");
        if (!(columns[index].searchoptions && columns[index].searchoptions.searchOperators)) {
            $searchOper.hide();
        }
    });
}

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: dataArr,
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    height: 'auto',
    hoverrows: false,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int"},
        { name: 'name', width: 70},
        { name: 'surname', width: 100},
        { name: 'startdate', sorttype: "date", width: 90,
            searchoptions: {
                searchOperators: true,
                sopt: ['gt', 'eq'],
                dataInit: function(elem) {
                    $(elem).datepicker();
                }
            },
            formatoptions: {
                srcformat:'m/d/Y',
                newformat:'m/d/Y'
            }
        }
    ]
});

$("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOnEnter: false,
    ignoreCase: true,
    searchOperators: true
});
fixSearchOperators();
```

It displays the same result like youth:

[image]