# How to increase the height of filter toolbar placed on top of JQGRID

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in which I have implemented the filter toolbar on top of the grid. Now I want to increase the height of all filter toolbar columns but I am not getting exact idea. I searched it on the web and got to know that it can be done by changing in .css file of the grid but not getting the exact code snippet.

Also I have to increase the height of grid rows.

```
$('#mytable').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autosearch: true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the filter toolbar are set by some lines of `ui.jqgrid.css`. Default height is 20px. To increase it for example up to 30px you can add additional CSS style definitions to your page which overwrite the settings from `ui.jqgrid.css`. For example [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HeightOfFilterToolbar.htm) (and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HeightOfFilterToolbar0.htm) which uses no searching operations) uses the following styles

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table { height: 30px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-oper { height: 30px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar th { height: 32px; }
```

It displays

[image]

I added to the demos the style described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17028298/315935) too just to improve the visibility of the input fields.

Comment: thanks sir for ur response...i added  <style type="text/css">
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table { height: 30px; }
         .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-oper { height: 30px; }
            .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar th { height: 32px; }
            </style>   in my aspx page but this not showing the desired result...

Comment: @vikas: Could you provide *the demo* which reproduce the problem?